# Read String from .txt file into 2-Dimensional Array; Ignore spaces in quotes; use only JDK

Tags: java, arrays

I frequent this site a lot, but I've come across something I haven't found that I can answer. This is similar to several other posts, here, but I have not found an answer to what I am looking for.

As a note, this is part of a school course, and this is currently a standalone java class of a larger java project. Currently, I am unable to edit the .txt file, and am restricted to using ONLY the following resources:

Standard JDK resources

```
java.util.Scanner;
java.io.FileInputStream;
java.io.IOException;
```

Using the following list:

```
john.doe    108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "dead man"  user
jane.doe    3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    "dead woman"    admin
barney.rubble   a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    "secret password"   mod
fred.flinstone  17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3    "R0ck3y business"   user
luke.skywalker  3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900    "usetheforce1234"   mod
leah.skywalker  0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7    "saveme"    admin
```

Each entry is separated by a tab.

The current java code that I have, is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream credFile = null;           // File input 
    Scanner inFS = null;                       // Scanner object

    final int NUM_ROWS_CRED = 6;
    final int NUM_COLS_CRED = 4;
    String[][] credArray = new String[NUM_ROWS_CRED][NUM_COLS_CRED];
    int i = 0;                                 // Index variable
    int j = 0;                                 // Index variable

    // Import file data from file.txt
    credFile = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    inFS = new Scanner(credFile);

    // Create array of file.txt
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_CRED; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_CRED; ++j) {
            credArray[i][j] = inFS.next();
        }
    }

    // Output array to verify array stored correctly.
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_CRED; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_CRED; ++j) {
            System.out.println(credArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

  credFile.close(); //Closes file.
}
```

My current output looks like this:
    john.doe 
    108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f 
    "dead 
    man"

```
user 
jane.doe 
3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5 
"dead 

woman" 
admin 
barney.rubble 
a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b 

"secret 
password" 
mod 
fred.flinstone 

17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3 
"R0ck3y 
business" 
user 

luke.skywalker 
3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900 
"usertheforce1234" 
mod
```

Expected Output:
    john.doe
    108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f
    "dead man"
    user

```
jane.doe
3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5
"dead woman"
admin
```

etc...

Solutions, guidance, pointers in the right direction are all welcome. Also, please remember that I am firmly restricted to not editing the .txt file, and only used the JDK and the 3 resources listed. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to split the whole line on `\t`?

Comment: `inFS.next();` will read until the next white space. Other solutions involve splitting on some other regex that accounts for the quotes

Comment: is it safe to assume that Scanner.useDelimiter() is allowed (vs. excluded due to its dependency on java.util.Pattern)?  you're delimiter would just be a `[\\t]` (pattern that matches a tab char) - i'm not sure if there's a way to create a regex delimiter that excludes tab chars that may occur in your quoted third field though

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! I tried to attempt to split on \t, but I wasn't successful. If you could provide an example of the code, to compare against what I did, it would be greatly appreciated!

I also attempted Scanner.useDelimiter but received "illegal charater: '\'" or "cannot find symbol, symbol: method useDelimeter(String)". Any advice or suggestions are welcome! I am very grateful for everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar to regular expressions? They're key to solving your question.

Like @cricket_007 already commented, the default `Scanner` delimiter is whitespace. That's why the scanner splits the quoted tokens away, which is something you want the scanner NOT to do, I believe. So you have to inform the scanner how to split the input tokens.

Within a row the tokens are separated by a tab character, and the rows are divided by a line break. So you can instruct the scanner like this:

```java
inFS.useDelimiter("[\\t\\R]");
```

This way, the scanner will give the quoted token as a whole. This regex means *split the tokens separated by a tab character OR by any linebreak*. [Pattern Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

If there's no linebreak in the input, the regex is simpler:

```java
inFS.useDelimiter("\\t");
```

In case the use of regular expressions is not allowed, you'll have to figure out another way to handle the quoted tokens.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I attempted what you suggested, but I'm not sure I did it correctly. I receive the error: "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javautil.Scanner.useDelimeter.next". Here is the line of code I tried `credArray[i][j] = inFS.useDelimeter("[\\t\\R").next();`

Comment: @BrandonP. insert the line just below `Scanner` constructor

Comment: Like this?
`inFS = new Scanner(credFile);
inFS.useDelimiter("\\t");`

Okay, I promise those are on two separate lines....but I can't figure out a linebreak in here, yet.

Comment: @BrandonP. that's it :)

Comment: Hmm, something else must be causing this to fail. I keep getting "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" when I add that. It doesn't reference that code, but references `credArray[i][j] = inFS.next();` Your thoughts on this @nandsito?

Comment: @BrandonP. are the lines split by tab or by newline?

Comment: BOTH! You are a genius! I got it working. It appears that this cruddy .txt file has /t, /r, and /n pieces of whitespace that the delimiter has to account for. Let me tell you, I cannot wait to be able to format my own files. Marked as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
final int NUM_ROWS_CRED = 6;
final int NUM_COLS_CRED = 4;
String[][] credArray = new String[NUM_ROWS_CRED][NUM_COLS_CRED];
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+");
try (BufferedReader r = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_CRED; ++i) {
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(r.readLine());
        for (int j = 0; m.find() && j < NUM_COLS_CRED; ++j)
            credArray[i][j] = m.group();
    }
}
for (String[] row : credArray)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

result:

```
[john.doe, 108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f, "dead man", user]
[jane.doe, 3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5, "dead woman", admin]
[barney.rubble, a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b, "secret password", mod]
[fred.flinstone, 17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3, "R0ck3y business", user]
[luke.skywalker, 3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900, "usetheforce1234", mod]
[leah.skywalker, 0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7, "saveme", admin]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this amazing bit of code. Unfortunately, my Professor has informed that since Pattern was not covered, I am not allowed to use it. Sadly, this has been my frustration, up until now.

Comment: @BrandonP. See [Java Scanner - Delimit by spaces unless quotation marks are present?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360694/java-scanner-delimit-by-spaces-unless-quotation-marks-are-present)